# Sync Internet Time with Computer

Tags: vb.net, time, synchronization, ntp

So im making a program that does have a license checking feature. This program only goes to a limited amount of people that are trusted (so I know they wont try to tamper with it)

What I want to do is sync the computers clock with a internet time (like time.windows.com or whatever is trusted) and if the computers clock does not match the internets, change the computers clock to match it.

I know theres NTP but theres not much projects that are in VB.NET (only one source i found but its broken and messed up, tried fixing it but only wasted time)

What im also worried about is if it can match the users Time Zone. Im trying to see if my program can get the time zone depending on their IP since I heard NTP does not support Time Zone and daylight savings.

Any good way to come across this?

Comment: If the computer is connected to the internet, chances are it's already being synced to a time source.  If it isn't, you're not going to be able to do this anyway.

Comment: It is connected to the internet but some dont always sync correctly or the user could change the time

Comment: If you doing it through program you must have to run your application with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a problem with a low rtc battery and had to update the date and time in XP.  First I found this class:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Daytime
    'Internet Time Server class by Alastair Dallas 01/27/04
    'Added a 'ping' trap to query each server before trying to open the stream.  
    'This led to greatly improved speed.
    '  From:                                To:
    '  For Each host In Servers             For Each host In Servers
    '   result = GetNISTTime(host)              If My.Computer.Network.Ping(host) Then
    '   If result > DateTime.MinValue Then          LastHost = host
    '           LastHost = host                     result = GetNISTTime(host)
    '           Exit For                        End If
    '            End If
    '    Next                               Next
    'Since the ping says the server is active I removed the conditional statement 
    'and assigned host to lasthost after a successful ping
    'I also adjusted the 'THRESHOLD_SECONDS' to 3
    'In 'GetNISTTime' I kept getting argument exceptions if 'timestr' was still null after the Try loop
    'so I added this after the Try loop:
    '               If timeStr = "" Then
    '                   Return DateTime.MinValue
    '               End If
    'Also updated server url.
    'Lloyd Folden 01/16/12

    Private Const THRESHOLD_SECONDS As Integer = 3 'Number of seconds
    ' that Windows clock can deviate from NIST and still be okay

    'Server IP addresses from 
    'http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi - current as of 04/16/12
    Private Shared Servers() As String = { _
          "129.6.15.28" _
        , "129.6.15.29" _
        , "132.163.4.101" _
        , "132.163.4.102" _
        , "132.163.4.103" _
        , "128.138.140.44" _
        , "192.43.244.18" _
        , "131.107.1.10" _
        , "66.243.43.21" _
        , "216.200.93.8" _
        , "208.184.49.9" _
        , "207.126.98.204" _
        , "205.188.185.33" _
    }

    Public Shared LastHost As String = ""
    Public Shared LastSysTime As DateTime

    Public Shared Function GetTime() As DateTime
        'Returns UTC/GMT using an NIST server if possible, 
        ' degrading to simply returning the system clock

        'If we are successful in getting NIST time, then
        ' LastHost indicates which server was used and
        ' LastSysTime contains the system time of the call
        ' If LastSysTime is not within 15 seconds of NIST time,
        '  the system clock may need to be reset
        ' If LastHost is "", time is equal to system clock

        Dim host As String
        Dim result As DateTime

        LastHost = ""
        For Each host In Servers
            If My.Computer.Network.Ping(host) Then
                LastHost = host
                result = GetNISTTime(host)
            End If
        Next

        If LastHost = "" Then
            'No server in list was successful so use system time
            result = DateTime.UtcNow()
        End If

        Return result
    End Function

    Public Shared Function SecondsDifference(ByVal dt1 As DateTime, ByVal dt2 As DateTime) As Integer
        Dim span As TimeSpan = dt1.Subtract(dt2)
        Return span.Seconds + (span.Minutes * 60) + (span.Hours * 360)
    End Function

    Public Shared Function WindowsClockIncorrect() As Boolean
        Dim nist As DateTime = GetTime()
        If (Math.Abs(SecondsDifference(nist, LastSysTime)) > THRESHOLD_SECONDS) Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetNISTTime(ByVal host As String) As DateTime
        'Returns DateTime.MinValue if host unreachable or does not produce time
        Dim timeStr As String
        Try
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(New TcpClient(host, 13).GetStream)
            LastSysTime = DateTime.UtcNow()
            timeStr = reader.ReadToEnd
            reader.Close()
        Catch ex As SocketException
            'Couldn't connect to server, transmission error
            Debug.WriteLine("Socket Exception [" & host & "]")
            Return DateTime.MinValue
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Some other error, such as Stream under/overflow
            Return DateTime.MinValue
        End Try
        If timeStr = "" Then
            Return DateTime.MinValue
        End If
        'Parse timeStr
        If (timeStr.Substring(38, 9) <> "UTC(NIST)") Then
            'This signature should be there
            Return DateTime.MinValue
        End If
        If (timeStr.Substring(30, 1) <> "0") Then
            'Server reports non-optimum status, time off by as much as 5 seconds
            Return DateTime.MinValue    'Try a different server
        End If

        Dim jd As Integer = Integer.Parse(timeStr.Substring(1, 5))
        Dim yr As Integer = Integer.Parse(timeStr.Substring(7, 2))
        Dim mo As Integer = Integer.Parse(timeStr.Substring(10, 2))
        Dim dy As Integer = Integer.Parse(timeStr.Substring(13, 2))
        Dim hr As Integer = Integer.Parse(timeStr.Substring(16, 2))
        Dim mm As Integer = Integer.Parse(timeStr.Substring(19, 2))
        Dim sc As Integer = Integer.Parse(timeStr.Substring(22, 2))

        If (jd < 15020) Then
            'Date is before 1900
            Return DateTime.MinValue
        End If
        If (jd > 51544) Then yr += 2000 Else yr += 1900

        Return New DateTime(yr, mo, dy, hr, mm, sc)

    End Function

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
        Public Structure SYSTEMTIME
        Public wYear As Int16
        Public wMonth As Int16
        Public wDayOfWeek As Int16
        Public wDay As Int16
        Public wHour As Int16
        Public wMinute As Int16
        Public wSecond As Int16
        Public wMilliseconds As Int16
    End Structure

    Private Declare Function GetSystemTime Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByRef stru As SYSTEMTIME) As Int32
    Private Declare Function SetSystemTime Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByRef stru As SYSTEMTIME) As Int32

    Public Shared Sub SetWindowsClock(ByVal dt As DateTime)
        'Sets system time. Note: Use UTC time; Windows will apply time zone

        Dim timeStru As SYSTEMTIME
        Dim result As Int32

        timeStru.wYear = CType(dt.Year, Int16)
        timeStru.wMonth = CType(dt.Month, Int16)
        timeStru.wDay = CType(dt.Day, Int16)
        timeStru.wDayOfWeek = CType(dt.DayOfWeek, Int16)
        timeStru.wHour = CType(dt.Hour, Int16)
        timeStru.wMinute = CType(dt.Minute, Int16)
        timeStru.wSecond = CType(dt.Second, Int16)
        timeStru.wMilliseconds = CType(dt.Millisecond, Int16)

        result = SetSystemTime(timeStru)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Then I used a form with a multiline textbox and 2 buttons, with this code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim DateTimeNow As DateTime
    Dim Args(1) As String


    Private Sub btnGetDateTime_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetDateTime.Click

        DateTimeNow = Daytime.GetTime + DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset
        txtDisplayInfo.AppendText(DateTimeNow.ToString + vbNewLine)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSetDateTime_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSetDateTime.Click
        Daytime.SetWindowsClock(Daytime.GetTime)
        txtDisplayInfo.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString + vbNewLine)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs
        If Args.Last = "-settime" Then
            DateTimeNow = Daytime.GetTime
            If DateTimeNow.ToShortDateString <> DateString Then
                Daytime.SetWindowsClock(Daytime.GetTime)
            End If
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub



End Class
```

To adjust windows date and time to the current one over the internet.  For some reason XP wouldn't correct date and time, so I needed this until I could change the rtc battery.  You might be able to use this.  According to the comments from author of the class I used.  Windows will automatically adjust the time for time zone if you use UTC time.