# Difficulty connecting to an ntp time server

Tags: vb.net, time

I am trying to use the following piece of code to connect to a time server and attain the time but have had no luck:

```
Dim ntpServer As String = "time.windows.com"
Dim ntpData(47) As Byte
Dim addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(ntpServer).AddressList
Dim EndP As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(addresses(0), 123)

Dim soc As Socket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, _ 
      SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)

soc.Connect(EndP)
soc.Send(ntpData)
soc.Receive(ntpData)

soc.Close()
```

Tracing through the program I can't get past the following line of code soc.Receive(ntpData). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It's been my experience that time servers can't always connect.  You might be better off using a list of servers(google) and pinging each one until you find an active one.

Comment: What does "No Luck" mean? Is there an error?

Comment: Nothing appears to happen - but I can never reach soc.Close()

Comment: The servers I have been using appear to be active because pinging them was successful

Comment: In this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878429/sync-internet-time-with-computer/16879398#16879398) is an answer that contains a class written in vb for connecting to time servers.  You might be able to find it of some use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I've actually seen this before and implemented it. The problem however is that the majority of servers do not appear to user tcp on port 13. Instead I think it's udp on port 123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide some basic information to the server:

`ntpData(0) = 27`

ntpData(0) contains a section called `firstByteBits`.

**This section needs to be set before sending the data to query for a reply.**

First byte is

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|LI | VN  |Mode |
```

- LI = leap indicator   (0 in sent data)
- VN = version number   (3, bits 3 and 4 set)
- Mode = Mode           (client mode = 3, bits 6 and 7 set)

`00011011 = 27 = 0x1B`

And possibly a better NTP server. The `time.windows.com:123` server pool is known to
be slow, sometimes not responding for a while, and of low accuracy. Better: `pool.ntp.org:123` (but please read what's written on [poo.ntp.org](http://pool.ntp.org) about regular use).

e.g. [RFC 5905](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5905.txt) for more details.